# How to edit a specific row/index in aura iteration by javascript?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura-iteration

Hi I am trying to edit a specific row in an iteration based on an onchange event.

One of my columns in my iteration is a picklist. And depending on what is selected I want the rest of the columns in the row to become enabled and autopopulated.

I know how to get the index of what triggered the onchange with the below code.

```
checkRow : function(cmp, event,helper) {
  var target = event.target;
  var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index");

/*get and edit columns where iteration index = dataEle

}
```

But how do I then edit that index of the iteration to enable the input fields and autofill them?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: how this method is getting called? can you add that code?

Comment: It's called by "onchange" which is inside of a lightning:select.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue with the following javascript:

```
checkRow : function(component, event,helper){

    var target = event.getSource();
    var rowIndex = target.get('v.title');
    var list = component.get('v.Items');

    console.log('Row Index: ' + rowIndex);
    console.log(list[rowIndex]);

    list[rowIndex].Quantity__c = 'Override';
    list[rowIndex].newElement = 'test';

    component.set('v.Items', list);


}
```

v.Items is a an attribute of type object[] which is used by my iteration.